# Saving a document to specific library

Tags: sharepoint-library

Is it possible to map Save to SharePoint to a specific document library, than depending on recent libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your desired document library as a network location.

Windows Explorer > Add a network location > Choose a custom network location > Internet or network address > Name the location

The new network location will be available from the Save As dialog in your Office applications.

Of course, this is a "per user" setting.